# Disabling the ability for JavaScript to load anything in a page

Tags: javascript, security

I'm in the process of white-listing sites I control and as a short-term measure I need to ensure that I disable the ability to load third-party scripts until I can do a roper audit. The alternative is to block access to all these pages which is a nuclear option I don't care for.

As such I am trying to write a small snipper of JavaScript that I can insert into the `HEAD` before anything else is loaded. This should gracefully block the addition of anything that can report back or dynamically load third-parties (that then in turn load more things...). It doesn't have to be bullet-proof (I'm not expecting any attempt to circumvent this by those who host external scripts).

This is where I am starting from:

```
(function(document, window) {

    var noop = function(x) { return [] };

    XMLHttpRequest = function(){}
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype = {
        open: function(){},
        send: function(){}
    }

    var restrictDocumentList = [ "eval", "write" ];
    var len = restrictDocumentList.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        document[ restrictDocumentList[i] ] = noop;
    }

    var restrictElementList = [ "appendChild" ];
    var len = restrictElementList.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        Element.prototype[ restrictElementList[i] ] = noop;
    }

})(document, window);
```

My questions are:

1. What situations should I be looking to account for?
2. Has anyone already done this? (I'm guessing and hoping thats a Yes)
3. Is there a better way?

For the record, for my situation, using a `META` tag to block external script loading is not an option. Example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'">
```

Comment: Where can the malicious part come from? If you control the page, what is the problem?

Comment: Another option is to use a `Service Worker` and intercept the `fetch` event, nice thing with this it handles CSS / Ajax, and of course other `fetch` API calls..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: @Amit Nothing malicious. I want to disable user tracking in short-term while page is refactored (bigger project I want to avoid) to ask for consent (as per EU GDPR directive that starts in May)

Comment: @Keith True, but I need to account for IE11 etc which do not support Service Workers

Comment: What server are You using? Are headers an option?

Answer (score 1):

**General recommendation**

You can encounter a load of problems while trying to solve this task in JS. I tried to do it as well and there were a lot of workarounds of the solutions I came up with, so I settled on the mentioned `Content Security Policy`:

> https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/

It is managed on the browser level so it is well above the `JS` sandbox. It is supported by [all the modern browsers](https://content-security-policy.com/).

You do not have to use it as meta tags (I do not recommend that way either). I prefer to add it as header in the firewall/proxy component. It gives more control for you (for example you do not have to redeploy the application on change, this becomes a configuration change instead of a programmatic solution). I use this tool to generate my headers for the applications:

> https://www.cspisawesome.com/

**If you really want to do it**

You need to cover a lot of cases. I went this far:

- Somehow disable all XMLHTTPRequests
- Somehow disable all document append + eval
- Somehow disable all "src" changes (**document.getElementByTagName("script")**)
- Somehow get rid of `iframes` (you can call methods in appended `iframes`)
- Somehow get rid of web assembly...
- the list goes on

The main concern (where I gave up) is that you can write anything in `JS` using only 6 characters... you can run this in your console:

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])()
```

It is basically no more than this:

> eval("alert(1)")

But we can imagine what this kind of codes could hide...

**TL.DR.**
CSP was created to signal the right behaviour to the browsers so they could take care of it, because in `JS` there is a workaround for everything.

I recommend not to use the meta tags but to add headers to make sure your site remains safe. This is quite easy if you are using for example Apache HTTPD:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';"
```